# change inline html image "src" with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inline HTML images.

For sake of brevity, let's just say this particular mark-up is really difficult to get to, where these two images live.

One image has an `ID`, the other image does not, but it has a parent div with an `ID`. What I would like to do is, update / change the `src=""` of each, with raw JS or preferably smaller jQuery.

**Image #1**

```
<img id="log_im" src="./wp-content/uploads/2015/01/old_logo.png">
```

**Image #2**

```
<div id="txt_left">
<img style="max-width: 300px; margin-left: -14px;" src="./wp-content/uploads/2015/01/outdatedimage.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#log_im").attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg');

$("#txt_left img").attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

First image:

```
$('#log_im').attr('src','newRoute.png');
```

Second image

```
$('#txt_left img').attr('src','newRoute.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Really no need to use jQuery for this:

```
var img_log_im = document.getElementById("log_im");

img.log_im.src = "image url";

var div_txt_left = document.getElementById("txt_left");
div_txt_left.children[0].src = "image url";
```

Alternatively:

```
var img_log_im = document.querySelector('#log_im');

var div_txt_left_img = document.querySelector("#txt_left img");
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery do both together -

```
$('#log_im, #txt_left img').attr('src','newRoute.png');
```